# Need help getting result_codes using JavaScript SDK on Node. Failed to make a payment

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk, operations

I'm using the JavaScript SDK in Node and have run into a problem making payments on the testnet. I catch the error but am unable to parse it to get at the result_codes which show as [Object] when I console.log it. How do I see what the result_codes are?

Example from console.log(error):

```
{ [BadResponseError: Transaction submission failed. Server responded: 400 Bad Request]
  name: 'BadResponseError',
  message: 'Transaction submission failed. Server responded: 400 Bad Request',
  data: 
   { type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed',
     title: 'Transaction Failed',
     status: 400,
     detail: 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html',
     extras: 
      { envelope_xdr: 'AAAAAIxgJdHRvUjFfPV7yVgiazXSBZWuVJv0eizUPO/GugFMAAAAZAB7Ra0AAAACAAAAAAAAAAEAAAALRmx1dHRlciBBcHAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAEpsuH8rByJ9lm8GkUTGq1eCLEy4D2fayXD3V95vO5w6AAAAAAAAAAABMS0AAAAAAAAAAAHGugFMAAAAQK1jjtWKT8U6KC7VsuylrU1Qn4pwvAbWdjy1IbiGqDkDXpdQP1fbrezu3nOgAwP8OocRr56GcgikwiT1G41/VgI=',
        result_codes: [Object],
        result_xdr: 'AAAAAAAAAGT////6AAAAAA==' } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Decoding](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAAAAAGT%2F%2F%2F%2F6AAAAAA%3D%3D&type=TransactionResult&network=test) the `result_xdr` shows the error code `txBadAuth`.

I couldn't locate the documentation for this error code, but you can reasonably guess that it is related to the transaction signature being incorrect in some way.

The [transaction envelope](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAIxgJdHRvUjFfPV7yVgiazXSBZWuVJv0eizUPO%2FGugFMAAAAZAB7Ra0AAAACAAAAAAAAAAEAAAALRmx1dHRlciBBcHAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAEpsuH8rByJ9lm8GkUTGq1eCLEy4D2fayXD3V95vO5w6AAAAAAAAAAABMS0AAAAAAAAAAAHGugFMAAAAQK1jjtWKT8U6KC7VsuylrU1Qn4pwvAbWdjy1IbiGqDkDXpdQP1fbrezu3nOgAwP8OocRr56GcgikwiT1G41%2FVgI%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) shows it was signed by the source account. And [this signer](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCGGAJOR2G6URRL46V54SWBCNM25EBMVVZKJX5D2FTKDZ36GXIAUYIAX) has sufficient weight to perform the payment operation that was attempted. So I'm not entirely sure what was wrong.

The `result_codes` value is printed as `[Object]` by node, because it is an object with two fields. A single code for the `transaction` and an array of codes for the `operations`. [Example](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/transaction-failed.html#example)

Comment: Transaction errors can be found here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#possible-errors

Comment: Decoding can be done with the SDK like this: `StellarSdk.xdr.TransactionResult.fromXDR(txResponse.result_xdr, 'base64')`